# How to know if php file is running?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php file which I think the code doesn't matter.

The problem is that I cannot allow it to run more than 3 times at a time since it makes many requests to the mysql database and becomes saturated.

I've seen some traffic light in php but I don't like it.

Do you have any better ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: How do you run your php script?

Comment: @KrisRoofe I search in URL https://mysiteweb/script.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are some approach you can follow to achieve your goal:

- the script create a file like "scriptNameIsRunning.txt"; the script first check for this file (do that at the top of the script): if it's found the script immediately ends. When the script complete delete that file (do that at the end of the script).
- the same as the above but storing the log in the database instead of using a file

To handle the case in which the script may fail during its execution, you may insert a [`try...catch`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) block and delete the file in the `finally` clause:

```
try
{
    // create the file
    // script work
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    // handle the exception, e.g.:
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
finally
{
    // delete the file
}
```

Comment: Thanks @user2342558 but If there is a problem during the script and it does not end, you cannot delete that file and no more can be executed, is there any way to verify that?

Comment: Thank @user2342558 it's working correctly!
I have edited the question with the solution in case it helps someone.

Comment: I think this can fail if system accidently restarts. The file persists! For simple use cases this is ok. But for a fault tolerant use case this cannot be used

Comment: Ah okay now remove it, sorry @user2342558